# DNS and understanding root servers

Tags: networking, dns, wireshark, query

Firstly, is this explanation on  how DNS works right?

When we visit a site, say (www.example.com),we are doing a lookup to convert the domain name to an i.p address. So, our computer first looks at its internal DNS to see if the host name is there. If the host name is not there, it goes to the root name servers(.). Now, the root name servers get the request and tells us that the request is at the TLD servers and gives us the i.p address of the TLD servers. Now, when we query the TLD servers, the TLD servers contain the extension of websites like .com,.org,.net etc.The TLD servers redirect us to the com servers,in this case, and we get the i.p address of the com servers.When we query the com servers, they have "example" in their list and redirect us to the example's DNS servers. When we query the example.com's server, we get an i.p address and access the internet.

My question is, for example.com, the authoritative name server would be the com server right? since it is the one giving us the information?

Comment: The authoritative name Server is the one that holds the records. That is the DNS server for example.com. In addition, computers don’t do root lookups. They have a DNS server configured, typically an ISP, and they query the ISP dns server. If a root lookup is required then the ISP dns server’s do it. Not your computer. It would be very inefficient and burdensome to have individual computers doing root lookups.

Comment: Say my dns servers have no cached data at all. So, it is going to go to the root, then TLD, then com servers and finally to the "example.com" servers. "The authoritative name Server is the one that holds the records" By this statement, would the authoritative name servers be the com servers?

Comment: Why would it be inefficient? Would it be extremely time consuming?

Comment: The DNS servers that host the domain example.com are authoritative. The root server delegates .com to a second set of DNS servers. Those .com DNS servers delegate .example.com to another set of DNS servers which is typically the servers you would specify when you register the domain. Those are the authoritative DNS servers - the ones you specify when you register the domain. See here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/reviewing-dns-concepts it is inefficient because there is a caching system in place for the very specific reason not to overwhelm internet DNS.

Comment: For example you’re not the only customer of your ISP querying for google.com. It is terribly inefficient to send your computer or DNS servers to root servers to do a recursive lookup. Number one you don’t have a direct connection to the backbone of the internet, like your ISP does - so it’s slower. Number two you can take advantage of cached results others have seeded for you. Even if you are running your own DNS like in Active Directory, it should be configured to use forwarders at your ISP, and only use root hints as a failsafe. It’s faster and more efficient, when milliseconds matter.

Comment: I got one more doubt. I have captive portal website and its extension is a "in". The authoritative name server for that website is a root server. Now an authoritative name server is a server that is giving the record to the client. What i don't understand is how can any website have its authoritative name server as a root server? Cause all the root server is doing is sending the query to a server that can do the job for you. It is not the one giving you the i.p address, but just redirecting you to the right server . Shouldn't the authoritative name server be the websites DNS servers?

Answer (score 3):

> My question is, for example.com, the authoritative name server would be the com server right?

No. Let `dig` it:

```
# dig example.com SOA

 ;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.            3600    IN      SOA     sns.dns.icann.org. noc.dns.icann.org. 2018080109 7200 3600 1209600 3600

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
example.com.            86400   IN      NS      a.iana-servers.net.
example.com.            86400   IN      NS      b.iana-servers.net.
```

Authoritative name server for `example.com` is:

```
a.iana-servers.net.
b.iana-servers.net.
```

That's the servers who are holding DNS records for `example.com`

Now we can query them directly:

```
dig @a.iana-servers.net example.com A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.            86400   IN      A       93.184.216.34
```

DNS resolver disassemble [FQDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) (Fully qualified domain name) from right to left.
First query going to root DNS servers asking who is authoritative DNS server in [TLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) for `.com`, then resolver query particular [TLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) for `example.com` from those servers.

```
# dnstracer -4 -r1 -s. example.com

Tracing to example.com[a] via A.ROOT-SERVERS.NET, maximum of 1 retries
A.ROOT-SERVERS.NET [.] (198.41.0.4)
 |\___ d.gtld-servers.net [com] (192.31.80.30)
 |     |\___ b.iana-servers.net [example.com] (2001:0500:008d:0000:0000:0000:0000:0053) Not queried
 |     |\___ b.iana-servers.net [example.com] (199.43.133.53) Got authoritative answer
 |     |\___ a.iana-servers.net [example.com] (2001:0500:008f:0000:0000:0000:0000:0053) Not queried
 |      \___ a.iana-servers.net [example.com] (199.43.135.53) Got authoritative answer
```

Let's try now another domain in `.com` [TLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain):

```
 # dig google.com SOA 

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
google.com.             345600  IN      NS      ns3.google.com.
google.com.             345600  IN      NS      ns4.google.com.
google.com.             345600  IN      NS      ns1.google.com.
google.com.             345600  IN      NS      ns2.google.com.
```

we will see, that authoritative name servers for [SLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-level_domain) `google.com` is different now.

> since it is the one giving us the information?

No, it is a chain of authoritative DNS servers.
Root DNS servers holding only top level zones also known as [TLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain), - such as `.com`, `.net` 
When resolver got authoritative DNS servers responsible for [TLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain), resolver query particular zone for
[SLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-level_domain)(Second-level domain, `example` in our case) and when it found authoritative DNS server for [SLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-level_domain) it query that server for [FQDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) (Fully qualified domain name) such as www.example.com

Usually people using internet provider's DNS servers that hold cached resolved DNS records. Such DNS servers called forwarding DNS servers. If they have records in cache, they reply to client immediately without bothering all intermediate servers starting from root. If such forwarding DNS servers doesn't have records in cache (or DNS record expired ) then forwarder resolving again and cache result. Client's DNS queries sent as recursive, that's means client should receive from DNS provider either an error or resolved record. Client shouldn't query chain of intermediate DNS servers on its own, it is job of forwarding DNS server who serves clients requests and cached results. This way forwarders reduce loading to intermediate DNS servers and reply to clients as soon as possible since providers DNS servers are closer to clients.
<sup>(BTW, public Google's DNS server is also a forwarder.)</sup>

DNS records has parameter TTL (time to live) that set in authoritative servers by owner of domain, so in case you expecting your IP address would change often, you can set TTL=5 minutes or if one don't want his DNS server be bothered too often then TTL can be set for a days.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly correct, but you've left out caching which is critical.

The first time you set up a simple caching only server, the only records it knows about are the `root hints` - this points to the root servers.  If you ask for `example.com` the root servers will tell which server to query for records in the `.com` - those are the authoritative servers.  Your DNS server then caches this information.  It will then ask the `.com` server(s) for the info on `example.com` and they will return a pointer to whatever name servers `example.com` is configured to use in the registrar database.  This info is cached as well.  Then your DNS server asks the name servers for `example.com` for the IP that maps to the name you asked for - www.example.com or whatever.

Now, lets say you then ask for `example2.com` - the `.com` server info is already cached, so instead of bothering the root server your DNS server goes straight to the `.com` servers, gets the name server info for the `example2.com` domain, and queries them.

Comment: You’re neglecting DNS delegation. The .com servers are not authoritative for .example.com. They simply delegate that domain to whatever DNS servers were configured when the domain example.com was registered. The same sever you configure all your A and CNAME records on for example.com is authoritative for the domain example.com itself.